# Return action doesn't change URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I was looking for a way to redirect with POST and the solutions I've found suggest simply using the action's name I want and fill the params. All of this within the same controller (let's call it Home)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Zoro(NameOfMyModel model, string stringName)
{
  //Do whatever needs to be done
  return Foo("bar",123);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string Name, int Age)
{
    //Code here that use the params
    return View();
}
```

So that works great except that when you look at the url, it doesn't show /Home/Foo, it shows /Home/Zoro. Can I fix this without using RedirectToAction? If I use it, I get this: Home/Foo?Name=bar&Age=123 Which I don't want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling directly calling `Foo()` use `RedirectToAction()` with [**this overload**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of it.

The way you doing calls the action on server but not actually redirects, if you want the url to change you have to redirect to the action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Foo", new {Name = "bar", Age = 123});
```

### UPDATE:

As in comments mention how to keep the data temporarily ,you can use `TempData[]` for it:

```
TempData["Name"] = bar";
TempData["Age"] = 123;

return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
```

and in that action you can get it from `TempData`:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{

string Name = TempData["Name"] as string;
int Age - TempData["Age"] as int;

return View();

}
```

### NOTE:

Note that `RedirectToAction()` only works with actions which are `HttpGet`, it will not work with `HttpPost` actions.

Comment: See edit for clarification on why I don't want to use RedirectToAction

Comment: if you want to update url you have to go with `RedirectToAction()` and  i am afraid you cannot call `HttpPost` action usning it

Comment: Can you offer a solution with RedirecToAction but storing the data somehow? That's the only thing I can imagine. Update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: you can use `TempData` for that purpose

Comment: @MrJinPengyou - your current Foo action Method is decorated with `[HttpPost]`.  You cannot redirect to another POST method from within a controller.  If you do not have a Foo action method that will accept `[HttpGet]`, then this will fail as no action methods will match.